# How to convert topk data from torch.tensor.topk() to a pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, matrix-indexing

I have a 1-d pytorch tensor and I got topk data of the tensor and indeces of this datas. How can I place each data in the corresponding position of a empty pytorch tensor?

The topk of this tensor elements and their indeces is got by:
`value, indeces = toech.topk(T,K)`
and I also have an empty tensor `t` of the same size as `T`. How can I copy each `value[i]` to `t[indeces[i]]`?
I have tried to use `for i in value` but this way is too slow when data isn't very small.

Comment: Can't you just do `t[indeces] = value` ?

Comment: @Toyo  `t[indeces] = value` works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
t[indeces] = value
```